# download zip file with data from multiple models in csv format

Tags: django, zip, django-import-export

I'm using `Django 2.0`

I have to download data from multiple models in csv format zipped in a zip file.

I'm using `django-import-export` plugin to generate `csv` file for the model data

What I'm doing is

```
def download_all_data(request):
    # user data
    user_resource = UserResource()
    queryset = User.objects.filter(username=request.user)
    data_set = user_resource.export(queryset)

    # favourite arbitrase
    favourite_arbitrase_resource = FavouriteArbitraseResource()
    favourite_arbitrase_queryset = FavouriteArbitrase.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    data_set_favourite_arbitrase = favourite_arbitrase_resource.export(favourite_arbitrase_queryset)

    response_user_data = HttpResponse(data_set.csv, content_type='text/csv')
    response_user_data['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="user_data.csv"'

    response_favourite_arbitrase = HttpResponse(data_set_favourite_arbitrase.csv, content_type='text/csv')
    response_favourite_arbitrase['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="favourite_arbitrase_data.csv"'

    zipped_file = io.BytesIO()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zipped_file, 'w') as zip_file:
        zip_file.writestr('text/csv', response_user_data)
        zip_file.writestr('text/csv', response_favourite_arbitrase)

    zip_response = HttpResponse(zipped_file, content_type='application/octet-stream')
    zip_response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=my_file.zip'
    return zip_response
```

**This is giving error**

```
object of type 'HttpResponse' has no len()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the actual data into the zip, not the bundled `HttpResponse`.

And according to the [`ZipFile.writestr` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.writestr), the first argument is the name to be used for the data.

You could something like this:

```
zipped_file = io.BytesIO()
with zipfile.ZipFile(zipped_file, 'w') as zip_file:
    zip_file.writestr('user.csv', data_set.csv)
    zip_file.writestr('favourite.csv', data_set_favourite_arbitrase.csv)
```